# Mongoosejs update document seems to work, but actually does not

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following code in my NodeJS server:

```
Shop.findById(req.params.shopid, function(err, shop) {
    if (err) return res.json(err);
    shop.name = _.extend(shop.name, req.body.name);
    shop.description = _.extend(shop.description, req.body.description);
    shop.social = _.extend(shop.social, req.body.social);
    shop.save(function(err) {
        if (err) return res.json(err);
        return res.json({
            type: true,
            data: shop
        });
    });
});
```

This code seems like the object was updated. 
    return res.json({
                type: true,
                data: shop
            });

But when I open the db, or refreshing the page, I am facing with the old data.

What is the problem?

UPDATE: Here is the schema

```
var ShopSchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    default: {}
},
description: {
    type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    default: {}
},
code: {
    type: String,
    default: shortId.generate()
},
pincode: {
    type: String,
    default: generatePassword(4, false, /\d/)
},
locale: String,
createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
defaultLanguage: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Language'
},
languages: [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Language'
}],
account: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Account'
},
social: {
    facebook: String,
    twitter: String,
    instagram: String,
    foursquare: String,
    website: String
},
images: {
    homepage: String,
    background: String,
    logo: String
},

address: {
    city: String,
    state: String,
    country: String,
    phone: String,
    email: String
}
});
```

Comment: Enable mongoose debugging and watch the console.

Comment: What data types are each of the fields? If they're arrays mongoose requires you setting `markModified` in order for a db write to occur. And your response is just returning the object you're making, not the object that the callback gives back which is why it would "appear" to be working.

Comment: Can you post the schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started to use mongoose-i18n plugin.

```
var ShopSchema = new Schema({
name: {
    i18n: true,
    type: String
},
description: {
    i18n: true,
    type: String
},
code: {
    type: String,
    default: shortId.generate()
},
pincode: {
    type: String,
    default: generatePassword(4, false, /\d/)
},
locale: String,
createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
defaultLanguage: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Language'
},
languages: [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Language'
}],
account: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Account'
},
social: {
    facebook: String,
    twitter: String,
    instagram: String,
    foursquare: String,
    website: String
},
images: {
    homepage: String,
    background: String,
    logo: String
},

address: {
    city: String,
    state: String,
    country: String,
    phone: String,
    email: String
}
});
```

Saving multilingual data is not a problem now.